# Merge or synonymise [ai] and [artificial-intelligence]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

The site currently has two tags for questions related to artificial intelligence:

- [ai](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ai) with two questions at the time of writing, and
- [artificial-intelligence](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/artificial-intelligence) with nine questions at the time of writing.

I have edited the two questions tagged [ai](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ai) to replace that tag with [artificial-intelligence](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/artificial-intelligence) (for which I also suggested a tag wiki excerpt). Those edits are still pending, but in the long run, it may make sense to merge [ai](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ai) into [artificial-intelligence](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/artificial-intelligence) or to turn it into a synonym.

---

Update 12.08.2020: The edits mentioned above have been accepted, so there are currently no questions tagged [ai](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ai).